# How to provide consistent timing of audio sequencing across various Android devices and OS Versions?

Tags: android, audio, timing, soundpool

I have created a metronome-type application with a specified swing interval of 750 milliseconds on the pendulum and playing a single audio file at the maximum swing arc... repeating the swinging of the pendulum and playing of the sound indefinitely. However, I am finding that the actual timing of execution of the code varies dramatically from device-to-device and even performs with variance on a single device. My intent is to swing the pendulum at the rate of 80 beats per minute and play the audio file with each "beat". I adjusted the 750 millisecond setting to accommodate the time required to play the audio file. This slightly reduced the millisecond setting from 750 down to about 680. I tested using various devices and found that the results of a one minute run of the metronome performed dramatically differently for timing as I tested with various Android devices even though I am defining my timing elements based on milliseconds.

I am using Android SoundPool to access a .wav file to play the sound.

I found quite a few references to Soundpool timing issues and concerns but have not yet found a viable and reliable solution to deliver consistent timing for an application like this.

It seems that the swing of the pendulum is pretty consistent based on the specified delay so I believe the variation is due to variable timing during execution of the SoundPool code playing the audio. Is there a reliable way to execute code to play sounds on a consistent and "exact" timing interval with Android?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is a handler.  This allows you to start the audio clip at exactly the same time regardless of how long the clip actually takes to play.  You don't need SoundPool for this, just SoundPlayer.

A handler allows you to schedule a message to be delivered to your code some time in the future.  Since playing a sound with SoundPlayer is asynchronous, you can use this simple mechanism to play a sound on a regular interval.

Here is some code to show how it might work.

```
    handler = new Handler() {

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message)
         */
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == NEXT_SOUND_MSG) {
                playNextSound()
            }
        }
    };

    // Set up media player for sounds
    player = new SoundPlayer(context);
    player.start();

    private void playNextSound() {
            if (mRunning) {

                // Play the sound
                int iSoundResId = item.getSoundResId();
                if (iSoundResId != -1) {
                        playSound(iSoundResId);
                }

                // schedule a message to advance to next item after duration
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(NEXT_SOUND_MSG);
                handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, interval); 
            }
   }
```